# The POST request is not executed by server properly if textarea has long content

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have the Laravel 5 web-application with the regular form with textarea
When I make POST request, if lehgth of request exceeds some threshold (the threshold seems to be smth like 200-300 symbols) I wait the responce from server very long and then "The connection to the server was reset"
Execution of php-script is disabled at the controller level (also tried to at routes.php; and also before the authorization middleware) -
the only thing that I ask from controller is to return me the raw post-data (simple 'Hallo World!' tried also)
The cuted controller method looks like:

```
public function handle_referencies( Request $request){
return '<pre>'.print_r(file_get_contents("php://input"),true).'</pre>';}
```

file_get_contents("php://input") - already in dispair, tried $_POST, in order to be sure that the request is really POST
With the shorter textarea content everything work properly, also the long-time script at background. At my local machine everything was good, at server logs I see nothing confusing
Apache has been installed and tuned (with virtual hosts) by myself - may be not so properly
php.ini virables, which I tried to change settings:
max_execution_time 300
max_file_uploads 50
max_input_time 300
max_input_vars 100000
memory_limit 256M
post_max_size 64M
in .htaccess at the app root is set to
LimitRequestBody 2147483647 (0 also tried)
help help...
sorry, if smth wrong with my question, - it is my very first experience at this service

Comment: How exactly long is it?

Comment: it seems to me as if the timeout is exhausted ~ 5min = 300sec

Comment: No, I'm asking how long is the content of the textarea?

Comment: " http://www.eldorado.ru/cat/2582505/
http://www.becompact.ru/acs/input/mouse/
http://computer-mouse.ru/" -  is good enough and one more string will be too long

Comment: You see, things like this wouldn't happen if you don't use frameworks...

Comment: I can't do things w/o frameworks yet - I'm only a couple of months as intern)...

Comment: Well, to each his own, I guess. Personally, using frameworks is a pain in the ass for me.